# NHibernate Image Storage - The length of the byte[] value exceeds the length configured

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate and am trying to store an image. Small images work, but larger images do not, and I receive this error when saving to the database (SQL Server):

> **Exception:** Error dehydrating property value for CFC.Domain.Vehicle.Image
>
> **Inner Exception:** The length of the byte[] value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter.

Here is my mapping:

```
mapping.Table("Vehicle");
mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "VehicleID");
mapping.Map(x => x.Year).Not.Nullable();
mapping.Map(x => x.Image).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(int.MaxValue);
```

The "Image" property is a byte[].

Note the CustomSqlType and the length, which creates the proper nvarchar(max) column in the database. I've read countless of other posts talking about similar issues, but none cover this specific error. It isn't that the data is being truncated and then saved, it just errors out before ever sending the SQL query.

The image I am testing with is just the standard Windows 7 sample images (Penguins.jpg of course) but an image around 1kb works fine.

I appreciate the help! Here is the beginning of the stack trace if it helps.

> [HibernateException: The length of the byte[] value exceeds the length
> configured in the mapping/parameter.]
> NHibernate.Type.AbstractBinaryType.Set(IDbCommand cmd, Object value,
> Int32 index) +207
> NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value,
> Int32 index) +397
> NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value,
> Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) +62
> NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
> id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
> Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
> ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) +350
>
> [PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for
> CFC.Domain.Vehicle.Image]
> NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
> id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
> Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
> ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) +510
> NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
> id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][]
> includeColumns, Int32 j, IDbCommand st, ISessionImplementor session)
> +59    NHibernate.Persister.Entity.GeneratedIdentifierBinder.BindValues(IDbCommand
> ps) +79
> NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo
> insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder) +102
> NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[]
> fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj,
> ISessionImplementor session) +265
> NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[]
> fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) +358
> NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute() +262
> NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) +56
> NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object
> entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean
> useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean
> requiresImmediateIdAccess) +811
> NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object
> entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean
> useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean
> requiresImmediateIdAccess) +543
> NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object
> entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source,
> Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess) +257

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately it is same problem without the length. I added a stack trace above to help as well.

Answer (score 14):

I know it's a little late to be posting a reply but I just came across this exact same error. Below was my resolution - hopefully it helps someone else in the future.

I changed:

```
Map(x => x.ByteArrayProperty);
```

to:

```
Map(x => x.ByteArrayProperty).Length(int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Interesting that the poster had something like this but with the CustomSqlType() before it. Perhaps removing that part of his mapping would have fixed it for him too

Comment: This worked for me. but it seems that it only fails for me when it is set as lazy. When it is not lazy, I already have another field with NVARCHAR(MAX) and I didnt need to add the Length mapping

Answer (score 10):

Sigh, sometimes after 2 days of research you just have to post a question to StackOverflow to find the answer right after.

I'm not sure of the underlying reason, but specifying the property directly when mapping was the problem. To resolve the issue I ended up creating a new "BinaryLengthConvention" below.

```
public class BinaryColumnLengthConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType == typeof(byte[]));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Length(2147483647);
        instance.CustomSqlType("varbinary(MAX)");
    }
}
```

Magically it all started working. Hopefully someone else that searches for that error message finds this useful.

Comment: If it's mssql we use image column types.  Then the mapping is just: `Map(x => x.Image, "IMAGE_DATA").Length(Int32.MaxValue);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while storing the big images. I resolved by adding length attribute to image field as `<property name="image" length="2147483647"/>`